# @foreach using dymamic model - how to use where clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamic model and I want to add a where clause in the view but now sure how to do it. I want to put where department = sales. Can I do that?  I know I can put a where at the select SQL statement, but now in the view I want to use a where clause for the category.

```
                    @foreach (SalesLinks salesLinks in Model.SalesLinks)


        model.Documents = GetDocuments();
        return View(model);



                private static List<SalesLinks> GetSalesLinks()
                        {
                            List<SalesLinks> salesLinks = new List<SalesLinks>();
                            string query = "SELECT ID, SalesLinksName, Description, Department, Catagory, SalesLinks_url FROM SalesLinks ORDER BY Department";
                            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBTConn"].ConnectionString;
                            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                                {
                                    cmd.Connection = con;
                                    con.Open();
                                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                    {
                                        while (sdr.Read())
                                        {
                                            salesLinks.Add(new SalesLinks
                                            {
                                                ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ID"]),
                                                SalesLinksName = sdr["SalesLinksName"].ToString(),
                                                Description = sdr["Description"].ToString(),
                                                Department = sdr["Department"].ToString(),
                                                Catagory = sdr["Catagory"].ToString(),
                                                SalesLinks_url = sdr["SalesLinks_url"].ToString()
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                    con.Close();
                                    return salesLinks;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Where do you want to add where clause? what is your data structure?

Comment: I updated the post. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq directly on the where clause:

```
@foreach (SalesLinks salesLinks in Model.SalesLinks.Where(x => x.department == "sales"))
```